How do you get a new access token (or refresh it) for Salesforce API?
This question is about connecting to our Salesforce API.

After some debugging, it seems that we are getting an error 401 from our Salesforce environment (but not when I run the exact same code using another endpoint).
I tried searching online, but I found information about "connected apps" - this is NOT a connected app.
My question is: how can we actually obtain a new "Bearer token" for the authorization?  Or refresh the existing one?  I am not our Salesforce admin - I want to be able to tell the person who is our Salesforce admin exactly what they need to do so we can get this fixed.  The connection definitely did use to work, so it could be that the token has expired.
Also our backend dev says that the code is written in such a way that we are receiving tokens automatically, since of course they do expire.

Have you logged a support ticket with Salesforce?

Not yet, but good point! Been going off the assumption that this is something we can just fix somehow in Salesforce. I’ll get a ticket raised :)

After some debugging, it seems that we are getting an error 401 from our Salesforce environment (but not when I run the exact same code using another endpoint) - including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour.
